# how can i center my flexbox in the middle of the screen?

Tags: html, css

Hi i want ask how can i center box (div) in the middle of the screen?

```css
.mybox
{
    display: flex;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to horizontally center an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-an-element)

Comment: Do you mean in the centre of the physical display or the centre of the browser's window? You probably want to search for "flexbox cheat sheet".

Comment: Is this all the HTML?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this code snippet.
This should work for any div.

```css
.center-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-screen">
  <section>
    <div>Your Content Here</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: how about when i want to center middle of the screen: inline-flex

Answer (score 0):

you will need the flex container and define the flex item. For example, If you want to use center

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="mybox"></div>
    </div>
```

and the css file should be:

```
 .container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
      .mybox {
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        background: black;
      }
```

or you can use margin:

```
.mybox{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: i got center on the top screen i want in the middle of screen

Comment: @cShaxu you can add ```align-items: center;``` in .container

Comment: how about when i want to center middle of the screen: inline-flex